# Optimal Solution for the following code to reduce running time

Tags: java, optimization

The following code is used to take a string input and find if any of its permutation are palindrome.
The code is taking o(n) time. I was hoping for a better solution.

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = myScan.nextLine();

        String a = "NO";
        permutation("", str);
        System.out.println(a);
        // Assign ans a value of YES or NO, depending on whether or not inputString satisfies the required condition
        myScan.close();
    }

    private static void permutation(String prefix, String str) {
        int n = str.length();
        String an = "NO";
        if (n == 0) {
            System.out.println(prefix);
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(prefix).reverse();
            String str1 = sb.toString();

            if (prefix.equals(str1)) {
                an = "YES";
                System.out.println(an);
                System.exit(0);
            }

        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                permutation(prefix + str.charAt(i),
                  str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i + 1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just count the letters. There can be one letter with an odd count (optional), all else must have even count, then there is a palindromic permutation.

Comment: For a test case cdefghmnopqrstuvw
There are 17 letters in total so do I have to count letter of each type and apply mirror image concept or you are talking about a different method.

Comment: "cdefghmnopqrstuvw" is this supposed to be a "palindrome" or a word with a palindromic permutation? Because it certainly is not.

Comment: Yes it is not but the concept that should be applied is to count letters of each type ?

Comment: Also, do you just want to test whether there _is_ such a permutation (yes/no), or do you want to _get_ that permutation, if there is one?

Comment: just test if yes or no

Comment: The code you provided is not O(n). It is O(n!). The answers below are O(n), and there exists no better complexity, since you have to visit all elements at least once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This looks a bit like homework, or a Java beginner's private excercise, so I'd prefer not to give you full code but just the idea, or algorithm, so you can come up with the actual implementation yourself.)

---

There is no need to enumerate *all* the permutations and see whether one of them is a palindrome. All you need to do is to count all the *letters* in the word and see if there is *at most one letter* that has an odd number of occurences. Take for example the palindrome `racecar`. It can be seen as having three parts: `rac e car`. The letters in the first and third part are the same, so each of those letters has to have an even count. The second part has just one kind of letter, but it can be repeated any number of times.

So, the basic algorithm is like this:

- create a dictionary, `map`, for counting the letters, e.g. `HashMap<String, Integer>` in Java
- for each individual character in the `word`, increase its count in the `map` by one
- create a counter for odd-numbered letters, e.g. `int odd_letters`
- for each character in the `map`, check whether its count is odd, and if so, increase the `odd_letters` counter by one
- if the `odd_letters` counter is smaller or equal to one, return `true`, otherwise return `false`

---

If you also need to know the actual palindromic permutation, if there is any, you can easily construct one from the counts map.

Let's say our word is `racecar`. Counts are `{a: 2, c: 2, e: 1, r: 2}`

- for each even-numbered letter, concatenate half of those letters' number, in any order, e.g. `acr`
- add the odd-numbered letter in the middle, if any, as often as it was counted: `acr e`
- finally, add the first part again, in reverse order: `acr e rca`

(Of course, `racecar` in itself already is a palindrome, but that does not matter; it's just easier to find an actual palindromic word than a word with a palindromic permutation.)

---

Finally, note that the complexity of your code is *not* *O(n)* (assuming that *n* is the length of the string). You are generating all the permutations, so this alone has to be at least *O(n!)*, as there are *n!* permutations.

Comment: Thnxx..Will try to implement it